# Can we install an Adobe AIR application on Microsoft Surface Hub

Tags: air, adobe, surface-hub

We have a rich interactive application build on Adobe AIR platform which runs on Windows 10. We want to make this available on our Microsoft Surface Hub with minimal changes?

I couldn't find any related information in internet.

Answer (score 0):

Dos Microsoft Hub run on Windows 10? Please share a bit more info so I can help.

If it does, then the app should run without issues. If it doesn't but it comes with a Windows Store, then you can change your AIR app to be added in Windows Store and download from there.